# Is there any deprecated elements and properties checker (according to w3c) like w3c validator?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c

Is there any deprecated elements and properties checker (according to w3c) like w3c validator?

Comment: Doesn't the w3c validator issue warnings for deprecated elements/properties?  It's a while since I used it, but I always thought it did.

Comment: Do you mean for inclusion into your own application? or to check the validity of your code?

Comment: @Andy No, it doesn't, and never has.

Comment: @David Dorward: ok, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any checker that lists them for you, but the Web Developer Toolbar from Firefox does that under the "Outline » Outline Deprecated Elements" command. Whait it does is, well, visually outline the faulty elements in your page.

You can also check which elements/attributes are deprecated in HTML. W3C is a great place to start: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html

Same goes for XHTML, Google will gladly provide URLS for checking the deprecated list of elements and attributes.

Of course, you can always validate with the W3C validators and check the error messages for "deprecated" when using a strict doctype.

I'd provided the links, but as I'm a new user, I'm only allowed one link per post. ;p

Answer (score 0):

Set a Strict doctype and run it through the W3C validator, it should trip up hard on deprecated elements (if it's in Transitional/Frameset and not in Strict, it's deprecated.)

**Edit:** If you are using XHTML, you can use a standard issue XML validator with the XHTML 1.1 or 1.0 Strict DTD.

Comment: There is a strong correlation between "Not in Strict" and "Deprecated" but it isn't 100%. e.g. `iframe` is not in Strict but isn't deprecated either.

Comment: Actually, it is. XFrames are thought to (eventually) replace frames in HTML. frameset, frame, iframe etc. should be considered deprecated (small d), and at any rate considered a Bad Thing™ (big B, big T).